# iOS: Image auto resize for all devices

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, autolayout

I'm trying to resize my image using auto layout and size classes but I can't seem to get it resized for iPhone 6+ the image is small compared to iPhone 4 or 5. It's my first time with auto layouts so I am kind of confused on how to do it.

Comment: The resolution of the iPhone 6+ is x3 compared to x2 for iPhone 4,5 and 6. Unless you specify the point size width and height for the UIImageView, loading the same image will appear smaller on iPhone6+. So either provide x2 and x3 images or provide a single image and use constraints to scale the size of the UIImageView. NB Scaling images will affect their clarity depending on the original size.

Comment: I have added the x2 and x3 but image is still small..I have specified the image size of the x1 in the xib with aspect fit.. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: So, on iPhone 4,5 it looks good?

Comment: Post some code or xib image...

Comment: Make sure you label you images using the standard naming. `MyImage@2x.png` and `MyImage@3x.png` and load just using `MyImage.png`. The system should then pick the right resolution.

Comment: post your constraints and problem images

Answer (score 0):

For all Iphone ,size classes is compact width and Regular height

so select this and after that add 4 constraint

1. Leading
2. Trailing
3. Top
4. Bottom to your super view

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing but still image is small on iPhone 6+

Comment: Check your size class again may be you have selected wrong size class

Answer (score 0):

You can replace childView to your imageView....

```
childView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

// vertical
childView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

// both
childView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Comment: Hi, he's asking about auto layout, your answer is with resizingMask, it's not the same

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the previewer in xCode, its part of the assistant editor and will probably help.

There is a guide here:
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-autosize-an-image-with-auto-layout-for-your.html

Answer (score 0):

Add "proportional width" and "proportional height" to superview and make "center horizontal" and "center vertical" or anywhere you want to position. And once check the content mode of image to "ScaleAspectFit" or anything else which makes the image bigger. If your image is of small size then it will show smaller on content mode "Center". Or use big images for all size devices. Make sure you are using @2x and @3x images.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Size class and then add the constraint by control+drag imageview to superview and add that constraints 
Leading
Trailing
Top
Bottom

Answer (score 0):

Just put constraints on image view, to 0 from all the edges. Don't add any more constraint. It will stretch and shrink according to device that you use. Regards